# Does wrapping my SVG icons inside a SPAN give me more styling capatilities and flexibility?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I'm currently building an icon component for my React appplication. It will receive a `path` string as `props` and render an `<svg>` with it.

Something like this:

**Constants File:**

```
export const ICONS = {
  BUBBLE: 'M512 64c282.77 0 512 186.25 ...',
  ENLARGE2: 'M1024 0v416l-160-160-192 192-96-96 ...',
```

**The component will be consumed like this:**

```
import Icon from './Icon.js';
import {ICONS} from '../../constants';

<Icon icons={ICONS.BUBBLE}/>
```

**Component File: Icon.js**

```
const Icon = props => (
  <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d={icons[props.icon]}></path>
  </svg>
);
```

**QUESTION**

Do I gain any CSS styling capabilites or flexibility by wrapping the returned `<svg>` inside a `<span>` or does every style that I could apply to a `<span>` I'm also able to apply to the `<svg>` directly? For example: display, position, etc. I'll be using styled-components to style it.

Something like:

```
<span>
  <svg width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d={icons[props.icon]}></path>
  </svg>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

No, I don't believe you gain any CSS styling capabilities from using either. But you do gain semantic benefits, which will bring SEO and accessibility benefits.

**LONG ANSWER**

It is in my opinion, that you should be wrapping them in a `span` element. This is because `span` is more semantically correct.

This is the following from W3:

> The  tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

I personally wouldn't think of an `svg` as a division or section in an HTML document.

If I had to try and justify using a `span` over a `div` for an icon, I would point at `wai-aria` best practices for an `accordion` component (or any other example on this link). Which can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/accordion/accordion.html). In the following link, they give this example:

```
<h3>
  <button aria-expanded="true"
          class="Accordion-trigger"
          aria-controls="sect1"
          id="accordion1id">
    <span class="Accordion-title">
      Personal Information
      <span class="Accordion-icon"></span>
    </span>
  </button>
</h3>
```

As you can see they are using a `span` element. Inside these tags I would expect an icon. So with your example it would look something like this:

```
<StyledIconSpan class="Accordion-icon">
  <Icon icons={ICONS.BUBBLE}/>
</StyledIconSpan>
```

I would put the `StyledIconSpan` on the component level and not in your `Icon` component. So `Component File: Icon.js` Will remain the same. And in you Component where it will be consumed, use it in the above example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's similar to what I have ended up doing. My generic icon component render an SVG and I consume it inside a `<span>` that helps me position it in the way that I need. Didn't know about the semantic concern. Even better practice then.